# Gold Part-Of-Speech tags

Tags: terminology, nlp, parts-of-speech, pos-tagging

I've read this term in many papers in NLP: (Gold POS tags).

what does it mean?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you perhaps list a few papers where you came across that term?

Comment: GOLD = [General Ontology for Linguistic Description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOLD_(ontology))

Comment: @Gaston Ümlaut, you're confusing this acronym with a well-known term used generally in a variety of fields: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_standard_(disambiguation).

Answer (score 1):

It refers to the set of "correct" part of speech tags assigned to the tokens (words and punctuation) in a corpus of sentences. The tags are usually annotated and vetted manually by linguistic experts, and used to train and test classifiers, parsers and other processing resources used to process natural language.

Comment: aha, so could we consider WSJ corpus as example of gold POS?

Comment: Yes, but the corpus itself isn't the gold POS standard - the POS tags are. And they themselves aren't a gold standard of POS tags per se, but rather only of the model chosen to describe the words in the WSJ. (The WSJ POS tags, for example, bears no resemblence to the  Stuttgart-Tübingen Tagset of the NEGRA corpus of German, to use a random example.)